# Using DataTable in DNX 4.5.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable

Is it possible to use DataTable in asp.net 5 vNext ?

this is my code plus the error :

[image]

the "**.Load**" method only returns Datatable and comes from classLibrary DLL.

I changed my project.json to these but it didnt help :

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.22",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "7.0.1",
    "System.Data.Common": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.0.0-beta-23516"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, as it stands, No. [See the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900493/asp-vnext-core-5-0-datatable)

It is very contentious as can be seen on [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1039) ASP.Net Core thread on GitHub